# Apex: Setting Properties with the Indexing Notation

Tags: apex, dynamic-apex

Is it possible to set a property on an instance of a class like so;

```java
MyCls item = new MyCls();

item['propName'] = propValue;
```

Comment: No, you can set like javascript notation for apex classes

Comment: Nice. Thanks both. I guess that leaves me with the option of using a Map instead of a Class.